# Xamarin.Forms reload a collectionview

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I am using Xamarin Forms and I have created a collection view, I am getting the data from an api after getting the device location, my question is how can I reload the collectionview? Here is my code:

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {

        APIClass aPIClass = new APIClass();

        public HomePage()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            getLocation();

        }

        public async void getLocation()
        {
            try
            {
                var location = await Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();

                if (location != null)
                {

                    HomeClass places = aPIClass.getUserPlace(location.Latitude.ToString(), location.Longitude.ToString());

                    HomeCollection.ItemsSource = places.results;

                    Console.WriteLine($"Latitude: {location.Latitude}, Longitude: {location.Longitude}, Altitude: {location.Altitude}");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

And my view:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="HomeCollection">
            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
               <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="150" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <BoxView Color="White" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                            <ContentView Padding="10" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding photos[0].name}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                            </ContentView>
                            <ContentView Padding="10" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                       Grid.Column="1" 
                                       Text="{Binding name}" />
                            </ContentView>
                        </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
```

Classes involved:

```
public class HomeClass
    {
        public List<PlacesClass> results { get; set; }

    }


public class PlacesClass
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<PlacesImageClass> photos { get; set; }
    }


public class PlacesImageClass
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public List<string> html_attributions { get; set; }
        public string photo_reference { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you binding to an ObservableCollection in the view(Xaml)?

Comment: added my view to my question

Comment: Thanks. Are you implementing INotifyPropertyChanged? If you don't the bindings won't fire when your collection view items source changes.

Comment: I do not believe so, as I dont know what that is or how to implement it

Comment: Ok, what is your HomeClass class? Can you show that?

Comment: Updated with HomeClass

Comment: You can achieve it `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface in your HomeClass like this thread:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: I don't often work with code behind and prefer MVVM, so i think creating a view model with an ObservableCollection<PlacesClass> property and binding your collection view to that may be the way to go. Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your view model will make sure that the bindings fire when your source changes.